# For finding intersection: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable:

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, intersection

Hi i am working with Pandas and have my two column, i wanted to calculate the Intersection of two columns , [image]

When I am trying to :

```
df9['C'] = [len(set(a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df9.Topic1_assignment, df9.Topic2_assignment)]
```

I get a **TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**, What is the possible reason for this error?

Here is my data: https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/Topic.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to process `nan` values differently because `set(np.nan)` raises a `TypeError`.

You can use:

```
df9['c'] = [len(set(a).intersection(b)) if all(pd.notna([a, b])) else 0
                for a, b in zip(df9.Topic1_assignment, df9.Topic2_assignment)]
```